# Python read multilayer PSD?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, layer, psd

Can you read a multilayered PSD image with Python? Ive tried PIL, but it only seems to access the first layer. Another problem is the result is black if the layer was set to "hidden" in the program.

Answer (score 1):

psd-tools will allow you to write scripts that read PSD files. I'm using it currently for a couple of things, and it's working well so far.

https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?
http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html

It uses Python Win32 extension.

Comment: I don't have photoshop, nor am I making a photoshop script. My code simply uses psd files. Id also prefer a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that. (Tip: next time add a comment to my answer instead of adding a new answer! ;) )